# Detect Chrome Extension Pinned in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The latest Chrome browser now shows a puzzle icon and doesn't automatically pin your Chrome Extension. Is there an API to detect if a Chrome Extension has been pinned? Can we detect from Javascript from a web page, or do we have to do the API through the extension itself? (I'm already assuming the extension itself.)

Comment: No. There's no such feature, https://crbug.com/1074161

Comment: It would be nice to have API(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some code you can use to check if your extension is pinned, and if not, send the user to a particular URL.

You can put this in your Background.js:

```
async function checkIsPinned(){
  let userSettings = await chrome.action.getUserSettings();
  if(userSettings.isOnToolbar == false){
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://example.com'});
  }
}
//Check if extension is pinned 
checkIsPinned();
```

This code is adapted from https://github.com/rustyzone/is-ext-pinned

**Warnings**:

- It requires Manifest V3.
- It only works when called from pop-up script (e.g. the one that runs when user clicks the extension icon on toolbar) or from service worker.
- It doesn't work from content script. That is, it always returns `{ isOnToolbar: false }` regardless of whether your extension's icon is pinned or not. You need to send a request to your service worker, run the code there, and then send the response back to content script. You can do that via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` or similar `chrome.runtime.*` methods.
- As of 2023-01-02, it's not supported in Safari ([see details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/action/getUserSettings#browser_compatibility)).

Comment: Turns out, that only Manifest v3 and higher will turn on the chrome.action feature. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/ And one must have the "action" key enabled in the manifest file.

Comment: @Volomike how one "enables" the "action" key in manifest?